# Expanation of "1#" token in W3C HTTP spec

Tags: http, bnf

I'm reading the **[W3C HTTP header spec](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html)** to look up the exact format of certain HTTP headers.  Like most specs, the HTTP header spec uses [**BNF**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backus%E2%80%93Naur_Form) to formally indicate a certain header format.

But I'm confused about the usage of the "`1#`" token, as in:

```
Cache-Control   = "Cache-Control" ":" 1#cache-directive
```

Given the context, it seems to indicate a comma-separated list.  But I've never seen this token used before, and I can't find where it's defined.  The spec itself doesn't define it as far as I can see.

Of course, I unfortunately can't simply do a [Google search](https://www.google.com/#q=what+is+1%23+token) for this kind of thing.  It's one of the rare cases where even a global, commercial-grade search engine can't produce the information I want due to limitations in the query parser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Source: [RFC2616 Chapter 2.1 Augmented BNF](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#page-15)

> ```
>   A construct "#" is defined, similar to "*", for defining lists of
>   elements. The full form is "<n>#<m>element" indicating at least
>   <n> and at most <m> elements, each separated by one or more commas
>   (",") and OPTIONAL linear white space (LWS). This makes the usual
>   form of lists very easy; a rule such as
>      ( *LWS element *( *LWS "," *LWS element ))
>   can be shown as
>      1#element
>   Wherever this construct is used, null elements are allowed, but do
>   not contribute to the count of elements present. That is,
>   "(element), , (element) " is permitted, but counts as only two
>   elements. Therefore, where at least one element is required, at
>   least one non-null element MUST be present. Default values are 0
>   and infinity so that "#element" allows any number, including zero;
>   "1#element" requires at least one; and "1#2element" allows one or
>   two.
> ```

**Edit:** The original question linked and qoutes `RFC 2616` which this answer is based on. However, the quoted RFC has been obsoleted by a number of newer RFC this year. The definition of the `1#` token has been updated in `RFC7030`. See [here](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-7) for the canonical source and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27311271/2912456) for the so-answer mentioning this change. Please be also aware that an errata concerning the related passage exists [here](http://www.rfc-editor.org/errata_search.php?rfc=7230)

Answer (score 0):

1) It's not a W3C spec.

2) RFC 2616 has been obsoleted. What's relevant is RFC 7230. See http://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/rfc7230.html#abnf.extension for the explanation of the syntax.